# Rails partials in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I've got a code that almost repeats itself in three of my controllers and i was wondering:
is there a way to render partials inside controllers? I'll clarify, i want to write the same piece of ruby code and render it in each one of the controllers. Anyone know a way to do that? thanks

Comment: I don't get your idea. Partials are part of the view logic and then you are asking for repeated code inside controllers. Can you put an example that clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions, the module, and playing with the inheritance

#### Module

Define a module with your custom code and include it in your controllers

```
module MyCustomModule
  def method_1
    #code ...
  end

 def method_2
    #code ...
  end


  def method_2
    #code ...
  end
end
```

Then in your controllers :

```
class MyController < AplicationController
  include MyCustomModule
end
```

#### Inheritance

If you don't mind having all your controllers ending up with these methods, simply define them in the application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...

  def method_1
    #code
  end

  # And so on ...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm very confused by your question; I don't see what it has to do with partials. However, if I understand correctly, what you have is something like.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def my_method
  end
end

class BarController < ApplicationController
  def my_method
  end
end

class BazController < ApplicationController
  def my_method
  end
end
```

And you want to DRY it up by abstracting the `my_method` method to a single place. The solution is to define it on `ApplicationController`, which the other three controllers all inherit from.